# google play doesn't work on my home wifi but works fine on every other wifi

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, 5.1-lollipop, google-account, connection-issues

I bought a new phone yesterday and i've had this problem since i got it. the phone works great with all wifi connections but not with my home wifi connection.
when it's connected to the home wifi i can use the browser to surf the web and some apps work fine like facebook - messenger - twitter (which i had to download them as apk) but google play doesn't work, at first it couldn't even get me to the page where i should sign in with my email and was giving me this error " there was a problem communicating with google servers.. " so i connected the phone with another wifi network, and could sign in to google play and downloaded some apps too and everything seemed to be working perfect, but not on my home wifi.

i should mention that when i update apps and switch to my home wifi the app which is being updated doesn't stop but continues to update through my home wifi, but when its done updating and the phone tries to update another app it gives an error msg again.

i've tried so many thing to solve this but none have fixed this for me. 
please help me.